# Map records from the model to classes

Tags: extensions, best-practices

In various tutorial, I see models, which provide data to the controller by means of arrays.

While this might be OK, I wonder if mapping these records to a model item classes wouldn't be better:

- If the extension would model item classes, it gets better type safeness.
- Furthermore, my IDE could provide auto complete hints.

**Should I use model item classes instead of arrays? Does this is a best practice?**

Comment: Can you post a link to a specific tutorial section that you are referring to where this array of data being passed so that we can see what you are seeing.